# C Win32: Window Automatically closes

Tags: c, winapi

I wanted to create a Word 'corrupter' which actually justs replaces some letters with some ascii alphabet. However, when the 'Generate' button is pressed, the window automatically closes

```
static HANDLE ghInstance;

HWND hwndEDIT;
int index[10];

static INT_PTR CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            hwndEDIT = GetWindow(hwndDlg, IDC_EDIT);

            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
            /*
             * TODO: Add code to process resizing, when needed.
             */
            return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (GET_WM_COMMAND_ID(wParam, lParam))
            {
                case IDC_GENERATE:
                {
                    char input[1000];
                    char output[1000][10];

                    int i, strLength, m, map;
                    int rNmb;
                    int chance;

                    GetWindowText(hwndEDIT, input, 1000);

                    srand(time(NULL));

                    strLength = strlen(input);

                    for(m=0;m<10;m++)
                    {
                        map = 0;
                        strcpy(output[m], input);
                        for(i=0;i<strLength;i++)
                        {
                            switch(output[m][i])
                            {
                                case '\0':
                                    continue;

                                case '\n':
                                    continue;

                                case ' ':
                                    continue;
                            }

                            chance = rand() % 100;

                            if(chance < 25)
                            {
                                rNmb = (rand() % 128) + 128;

                                output[m][i] = rNmb;
                            }
                        }
                        index[m] = SendDlgItemMessage(hwndDlg , IDC_LISTBOX, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)output[m]);

                        map++;
                        SendDlgItemMessage(hwndDlg, IDC_LISTBOX, LB_SETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)index[m], (LPARAM)map);
                    }
                }
                case IDC_CLOSE:
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, TRUE);
                    return TRUE;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;

        /*
         * TODO: Add more messages, when needed.
         */
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I do not see any link between the generate button and the close command

Comment: The `IDC_GENERATE` case falls through to the `IDC_CLOSE` case. Switch blocks fall through unless you explicitly break or return.

Comment: no break; after case IDC_GENERATE: as result you execute case IDC_CLOSE:
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, TRUE);

Comment: Hey, you recently [raised an improvement request on this piece of documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/2256/7403). Since there's no way to post comments or communicate with you via the Docs interface, I'm abusing comments to do it here. Can you give me a hint as to what you find wrong with the example code? Specifically, in what way is it unclear or incomplete? (It obviously doesn't have formatting problems.) What else would you like to see? I reviewed the submission, and it looks reasonable to me. Did you test the code and find out it doesn't work?

Comment: @CodyGray Risky move there, anyways, the code you provided worked, but had little explanation. I had not have a clue what were you doing. However, I dismissed my improvement request and down vote. Also, you could request for a comment function. Its still in beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a break statement.

The case `case IDC_GENERATE` falls directly into:

```
case IDC_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hwndDlg, TRUE);
    return TRUE;
```

You could use functions to make the code readable, and this error would probably be caught.

Comment: I like the last line. With some refactoring of the cases into separate functions, the fact `break` is missing would indeed be more visible. Very long functions are always hard to read.